# Plotting projections of curves and surfaces in 3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, projection

I would like to adapt the following code to generate two pictures: the first one is identical to the one it generates, but with the projections on the $xy$ plane of the caps that appear on the paraboloid (with dashes coming from the surface to the plane if possible, or any indication of a projection, and a ``label" close to them, say $U_1$ and $U_2$):

```
w1 = Plot3D[.4*x^2 + .4*y^2, {x, .6, 1.2}, {y, .4, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Opacity[0.5]}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   Ticks -> None];
w2 = Plot3D[.4*x^2 + .4*y^2, {x, .5, 1.1}, {y, -1.8, -1.2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Opacity[0.5]}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesStyle -> Opacity[0], 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic];
w3 = Plot3D[.4*x^2 + .4*y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {LightGreen, Opacity[0.2]}, Mesh -> None, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   AxesStyle -> Opacity[0], BoxRatios -> Automatic];
Show[w1, w2, w3, PlotRange -> All]
```

I wasn't able to get a partial code for the second picture, but here's a rough hand version of it (apologies in advance for my poor drawing skills. Also, I accidentally reversed $x$ and $y$ in the picture): [image]

The idea is simple: two parabolas on the $xz$ and $yz$ plane, two arcs, their projections on the $x$ and $y$ axes and the rectangle given by the cartesian product of their projections with the label (say, $K$). Is it possible to do that with a code similar to the one above or does one need other tools? Any help would of course be appreciated :)

Comment: The y-axis should reverse the direction since Mathematica is using right-hand orientation.

Comment: Thanks, I added a note to the question (my mistake).